# print variable to output text file in excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

The below `excel 2010 vba` runs perfectly except I can not seem to get the variable `process` (time elapsed) to print from the `Call Perl section` to the `analysis.txt`, which captures some information regarding the analysis.  Thank you :).

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim MyBarCode   As String      ' Enter Barcode
Dim MyScan      As String      ' Enter ScanDate
Dim MyDirectory As String

'GET USER INPUT '
Line1:
MyBarCode = Application.InputBox("Please enter the last 5 digits of the barcode", "Bar Code", Type:=2)

If MyBarCode = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
Do
    MyScan = Application.InputBox("Please enter scan date", "Scan Date", Date - 1, Type:=2)
    If MyScan = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
    If IsDate(MyScan) Then Exit Do
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date format. ", vbExclamation, "Invalid Date Entry"
Loop

'CREATE NEXUS DIRECTORY AND VERIFY FOLDER '
MyDirectory = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy") & "\"
If Dir(MyDirectory, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir MyDirectory
Else
    MsgBox ("Already exsists! Please enter again")
    GoTo Line1
End If

'Write to text file
    Open MyDirectory & "sample_descriptor.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Experiment Sample" & vbTab & "Control Sample" & vbTab & "Display Name" & vbTab & "Gender" & vbTab & "Control Gender" & vbTab & "Spikein" & vbTab & "Location" & vbTab & "Barcode" & vbTab & "Medical Record" & vbTab & "Date of Birth" & vbTab & "Order Date"
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block1.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block1.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C201").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D201").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E201").Value
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block2.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block2.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C202").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D202").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E202").Value
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block3.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block3.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C203").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D203").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E203").Value
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block4.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block4.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C201").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D204").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E204").Value
    Close #1

'CREATE ANALYSIS LOG '
 Dim Process As String

 Open MyDirectory & "analysis.txt" For Output As #2
 Print #2, "Analysis done by" & " " & Environ("UserName") & " " & "on" & " " & Date & " " & "at" & " " & Time & " " & "and took" & Process & "to complete"
 Close #2

'CONFIRM ENTRIES '
Dim Patient As String
Dim Barcode As String
Dim Directory As String
Dim MyFile As Variant
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim i As Long

Directory = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy")

  Patient = ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value
Barcode = "2571683" & MyBarCode
  MsgBox "The patients that will be analyzed are:" + Patient & "The barcode is:" + Barcode


  iYesNo = MsgBox("Do the patients and barcode match the setup sheet?", vbYesNoCancel)
      Select Case iYesNo
             Case vbYes
             GoTo Line2
             Case vbNo
             MsgBox ("Doesn't match! Please enter again")
             Call DeleteFolder(Directory)
             GoTo Line1
       End Select

'ADD VBA REFERENCE: MICROSOFT XML, v3.0 or v6.0 '
Line2:
Dim oXMLFile As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim imgNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, destNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim XML­File­Name As String

XML­File­Name = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\imagene.bch"
oXMLFile.Load (XML­File­Name)

'EXTRACT NODES INTO LIST AND REWRITE NODES '
Set imgNode = oXMLFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Batch/Entry/Image")
imgNode(0).Text = "I:\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532.tif"
imgNode(1).Text = "I:\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635.tif"

Set destNode = oXMLFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Batch/Entry/Destination")
destNode(0).Text = MyDirectory
destNode(1).Text = MyDirectory

'SAVE UPDATED XML '
 oXMLFile.Save XML­File­Name

'UNINTIALIZE OBJECTS '
Set imgNode = Nothing
Set destNode = Nothing
Set oXMLFile = Nothing

'CALCULATE TIME FOR PROCESS '
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

StartTime = Timer ' define start time
'CALL JAVA PROGRAM USING SHELL AND COMPLETE PROCESS '
Dim wshell As Object
Set wshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")

Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
wshell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\java.bat", windowsStyle, waitOnReturn

'UPDATE PERL VARIABLES USING SHELL '
 Dim PerlCommand As String, PerlParameters As String, VarDirectory As String
 Dim var As String, var1 As String, var2 As String, var3 As String

 MsgBox ("Verifying spike-ins, please wait")

VarDirectory = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy")

var = VarDirectory
var1 = "sample_descriptor.txt"
var2 = "C:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\test_probes8.txt"
var3 = var & "\" & "output.txt"

'CALL PERL '
PerlCommand = """C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\perl.bat"""
PerlParameters = """" & var & """" & " " & _
"""" & var1 & """" & " " & _
"""" & var2 & """" & " " & _
"""" & var3 & """"
CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run PerlCommand & "  " & PerlParameters, windowsStyle, waitOnReturn

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss") 'elapsed seconds
Process = MinutesElapsed & " minutes"

 iYesNo = MsgBox("ImaGene and spike-in anlysis complete, do you want to run NxClinical?", vbYesNoCancel)

Select Case iYesNo

       Case vbYes
'CALL AND EXECUTE NXCLINICAL '
Dim x As Variant
Dim Path As String

'SET INSTALLATION PATH '
Path = "C:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\NxClinical Client\NxClinical.exe"

x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)

        Case vbNo
 'CLOSE AND EXIT '
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.Quit
End Select

End Sub
```